# JVM on OS X always exiting with status 0 (as captured in Bash script)?

Tags: java, macos, bash, exit

I have a very simple Java class, that does nothing else but:

```
public class TestMain {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Running!");
    System.exit(1111);
  }
}
```

, packed into a `TestOSX.jar` file.

While on Windows I can run the above snippet and show that `%ERRORLEVEL%` has the expected value, I get a different outcome on OS X.

Given `test.sh` containing:

```
#!/bin/bash

"/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java" -jar TestOSX.jar 
wait $!
updater_exit_val=$?
echo $updater_evit_val
```

, I always print 0.

Setup: OS X 10.11.1, Oracle Java 8 u60.

What trivial detail am I missing here?

Comment: echo $updater_e**vi**t_val ...?

Comment: else comment out the `wait` and see if that changed things. Also the max int for shell exits is 255. Your 1111 will be mod 255 (I'm pretty sure). Good luck.

Comment: @MadProgrammer - well, it was not *that* trivial, but thanks for catching that! In the original script on the Mac (I posted this from another system) I don't have the typo. I'll just leave my original post as it is, so that it makes sense to others reading. I'll get back to everyone else's suggestions/answers as soon as I get access to the Mac. Thank you for now.

Comment: @shellter: Commenting wait did the trick. It seems I didn't get the difference between running just another command in the shell vs a different program. The observation about mod 255 was spot-on as well. Thanks!

Comment: @shellter: FWIW, it seems to actually be modulo 256. I would've guessed 255 as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not send your java process to the background with `&`. Thus `wait` is executed after the java process exits. It can't find the process you try to wait for, because it already exited and giving return code 0 because of that. `$?` returns the return code of the last command (in your case `wait`).

You can either remove wait from your script, or you send your java process to the background by adding `&` at the end.

Comment: Commenting the wait solved the issue. I appreciate the clear explanation.